# Java for loop - code efficiency

Tags: java, performance

I have an array of 10,000 elements and i want to loop through and find a particular number say '6573'.

Example

```
 for(int i=0;i<=user.length;i++)
    {
        if(user[i]=="6573")
            System.out.println("Found it!!!");
    }
```

Could you please suggest a way to improve the performance of the code.

Thanks

Comment: Use a different data structure, or keep your array sorted.

Comment: This won't work, use `i < user.length` instead. Remember index starts at `0`!

Comment: this question belongs to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You can never find that element with the current way. Always use `equals()` method for String value comparisons, the condition in the `for` loop must be `i < user.length`, if you want to avoid `AIOOBE` and lastly, try to use a Map if you want faster retrievals(though inserts would be time consuming).

Answer (score 2):

- Use `.equals` instead of `==` to compare strings
- Break when a match is found
- he end condition must be `i < user.length` to prevent `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`:

--

```
for(int i = 0; i < user.length; i++) {
    if("6573".equals(user[i])) {
        System.out.println("Found it!!!");
        break;
    }
}
```

Note that I inverted the `.equals()` call to prevent `NullPointerException` if the array contains `null` values.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to do it once then that's about it. If you try to find several users in that list then you could use a set for O(1) search:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(user));
if(set.contains("6573"))
        System.out.println("Found it!!!");
```

And it may actually make sense to store your users directly in that set in the first place instead of using an array.

Answer (score 0):

if the array elements is in order(sorted) then u can use the binary search .. it will increase the performance of your program.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the Array using `sort()` (efficiency `O(n Log n)` and use `binary search (O(log n) )` .. I think this will be more efficient than your current efficency i.e, `O(n).`. Just giving details of @abhi's answer...

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
int index = -1;  
boolean found = false;  
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)  
{  
   if(array[i].equalsIgnoreCase(userInput))  
   {  
       index = i;
       found = true;
       break;
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use `multi-threading` and make for example 2 pointers, one travel from the start of the array and one form the end till the middle of the array.

It will use more processing but less time.